# Prove using induction that a $n\times m$ matrix with $n$ distinct rows also has a submatrix $n \times (n-1) $with $n$ distinct rows.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, induction

Let $A$ be a matrix with $n$ rows and $m$ columns ($m\geq n\geq 2$) such that all the $n$ rows are distinct. (Two rows indexed by $i_1, i_2 \in [n]$ are said to be distinct iff there exists a column $j \in [m]$ where they differ i.e., $A(i_1,j) \ne A(i_2,j)$).

Prove that there exists an $n\times(n-1)$ submatrix $A'$ of $A$ (i.e. $A'$ is obtained from $A$ by picking $n-1$ columns) 
such that $A'$ also has $n$ distinct rows.

I tried to use induction on $n$ because I think that should be the simplest approach, but I couldn't get further.

Answer (score 0):

The induction step ($n-1 \implies n$) goes like this.

Suppose you have $n-2$ columns such that the $n-1 \times n-2$ submatrix $B$ formed by the first $n-1$ rows and those columns has all distinct rows.  These columns of the $n$'th row can only match at most one of the rows of $B$.  If it doesn't match any of them, choose another column arbitrarily.  If it does match one, let's say the $i$'th row, choose a column where the $i$'th and $n$'th rows differ.